# Custom Controller Method, Route, & ERB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, model-view-controller

I have a search form and I need to be able to filter based on whether or not pets are allowed, but I'm not sure how to accomplish this. I have setup a route, a controller method, and a button but none of that seems to be working.

listings_controller:

```
def pets_allowed
  @listings = @listings.where(pets: true)
end
```

routes.rb:

```
  get "pets_allowed" => "listings#pets_allowed"
```

html.erb file:

```
<div>
  <%= link_to 'Pets Allowed', pets_allowed_path, :class => 'button btn-transparent' %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you meant

```
def pets_allowed
  @listings = Listing.where(pets: true)
end
```

Comment: I have tried that. I get a "Template is missing" error. Thoughts?

Comment: Sure, Template is missing lol. Your default template name should be pets_allowed.html.erb

Comment: A new template will redirect users to that page/template. Or you could render the template you want (i.e. your index ) or use ajax to get and return the results on the current page.

Comment: @user3366016 What if I wanted to just have a button and if there was a listing with the boolean marked true, when the search button is clicked it would return only those listings?

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic example of another way to do what I think you're aiming for (as per comments).

This adds a new action in your Listings controller that returns a filtered list of results based on the users input from the search form on your listings index page. The results are rendered using the same index template. The logic for checking/retrieving results can be modified based on what you want. If you just want a check box, only have a checkbox or a button that calls the action.

You could do similar logic but use ajax to return the results and render them on the index template using a partial.

This should give you enough information to google for examples/tutorials and try different ways of getting what you want.

**Add a route:**

```
# routes.rb

get 'pets_allowed', to: 'things#pets_allowed'
```

**Add a new action:**

```
  # listings_controller.rb

  # GET /things
  # GET /things.json
  def index
    @listings = Listing.all
  end

  # Get /pets_allowed
  def pets_allowed
    @listings = Listing.where("name LIKE ? and pets = ?", "%#{params[:name]}%", params[:pets] )
    render template: "listings/index",  variable: @listings
  end
```

**Add a search form to your view:**

```
# listings/index.html.erb

<h1>Listings</h1>

<%= form_tag('pets_allowed', method: 'GET' ) do %>
    <%= label_tag :name %><br>
    <%= text_field_tag :name %>
<br>
    <%= label_tag :pets %><br>
    <%= check_box_tag :pets, 't' %>
<br>

  <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Listing name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @listings.each do |listing| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= listing.name %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Listing', new_listing_path %>
```